# How can I intercept clipboard operations and add them to a JList?

Tags: java, clipboard

Whenever <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is pressed, I would like to add the clipboard contents to a `JList` as an element.  Basically, I want the code below to execute when <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is pressed.

How can I do this?

```
current=getClipboardContents();
model.addElement(current);
```

`current` is a `String` in Clip class and `model` is the default model for `JList`

Comment: Why do you think this needs a separate thread?  If it's a Swing app, why wouldn't you just let the Swing thread handle it?

Comment: Olease replace the "java help please" with a summary of your queszion, like "clip board access" or somthing that makes sense.

Comment: Are you trying to continuously read the clipboard and copy its content to your application? What Ctrl+C means in this context? This is for console applications, not GUI-based ones.

Comment: Should be Ctrl+V, the standard way in Windows (and others) to paste the clipboard content into your application.

Comment: If the user presses `Ctrl-C` while MS Word (or any other app.) is in focus, do you expect to see the copied text in the `JList`?

Comment: @duffymo i have to constantly check whats in clipboard

Comment: @David yes i m continuously reading the system clipboard,your right Control+c means nothing and NO ctrl+V is not required

Comment: @andrew no i dont expect MS WORD but anything in normal font and standard text should

Answer (score 1):

You would probably use [Key Bindings](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/key-bindings/) for this.

The Action for the KeyStroke would look something like:

```
Transferable t = c.getContents( null );

if ( t.isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor.stringFlavor) )
{
    Object o = t.getTransferData( DataFlavor.stringFlavor );
    String data = (String)t.getTransferData( DataFlavor.stringFlavor );
}
```

> yes i m continuously reading the system clipboard

Doesn't sound like a very good design. What if something gets replaced in the clipboard before you copy the contents and add it to your JList?

Anyway you've already been given code to copy text from the clipboard. I would use a Timer to schedule the polling so that the update to the ListModel is done on the EDT.